# Rails. I can't see my plan subscription in Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_XYZ") console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stripe-payments

I have created my product with price and when I go to consult the clients the subscription field does not appear.

```
# rails console
Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_XYZ")
```

However, the subscription appears when I run in the console:

```
Stripe::Subscription.retrieve("sub_1XYZ")
```

I'd like it to appear when I do a query Stripe::Customer.retrieve, as I need the "subscription" field appears it

If there is any way to retrieve the subscription field in customer I would be very grateful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-subscriptions), the `subscriptions` are [expandable](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) and not included by default.

You can get these, but you need to explicitly request them via expansion:

```
Stripe::Customer.retrieve({
  id: 'cus_123',
  expand: ['subscriptions'],
})
```

Comment: It helped me, thank you very much for your help and for the information attached: D